# Group objects by a series of common IDs and select a grouping based on the sum of a different key in LINQ

Tags: linq

So I have a bit of an academic question. I was able to solve this using a brute force approach, but I believe it to be solvable more elegantly in LINQ - however, I can't find a way to do so. Solution can be C# or VB, it's the LINQ itself that is giving me trouble.

I have the following object:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId {get; set; }

    public int Bar {get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains list of FooId
    /// </summary>
    public int[] Stackability
}
```

What I need to do is find all possible groupings of `Foo`s based on their `Stackability` (i.e.: common `FooId` in their Stackability list), then select the grouping that has the highest sum of `Bar`.

So, for example: I have Foos with Ids of 1, 2 and 3.

```
+-------+-----+--------------+  
| FooId | Bar | Stackability |  
+-------+-----+--------------+  
| 1     | 5   | 2, 3         |  
+-------+-----+--------------+  
| 2     | 2   | 1, 3         |  
+-------+-----+--------------+  
| 3     | 6   | 1            |  
+-------+-----+--------------+
```

- Foo 1's Stackability contains values of 2 and 3 and it has a Bar of 5.
- Foo 2's Stackability contains values of 1 and 3 and it has a Bar of 2.
- Foo 3's Stackability contains a value of 1 and it has a bar of 6.

In this example, Foo 1 can Stack with Foo 2 and Foo 3, Foo 2 can stack with Foo 1 and Foo 3, and Foo 3 can only stack with Foo 1.

*Note that the stacking has to be reciprocal (so even though Foo 2 can stack with Foo 1 and Foo 3, Foo 3 can only stack with Foo 1, which means **Foo 2 can actually only stack with Foo 1**).*

This would give us the following groupings with their corresponding sums for `Bar`:

- { Foo 1, Foo 2 } - Bar == 7
- { Foo 1, Foo 3 } - Bar == 11
- { Foo 1 } - Bar == 5
- { Foo 2 } - Bar == 2
- { Foo 3 } - Bar == 6

In this case, the correct grouping would be Foo 1 and Foo 3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `based on their Stackability` what does this mean?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "all possible groupings of Foos based on their Stackability". Sample input, expected output and an explanation would make it a lot clearer.

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca It's a field on there.

Comment: Yes, but how do you compare according to this field? the same values? order is important?

Comment: Sorry guys, updating the question now to clarify. I originally had a longer explanation written, but figured it was overkill. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly the following will return the correct grouping.

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new[] {
        new Foo {FooId = 1, Bar = 5, Stackability = new int[] {2, 3} },
        new Foo {FooId = 2, Bar = 2, Stackability = new int[] {1, 3} },
        new Foo {FooId = 3, Bar = 6, Stackability = new int[] {1} } };

    var result = data
        .Select(d => new
        {
            Foo = d,
            Matches = data.Where(dm => dm.Stackability.Contains(d.FooId))
        })
        .Select(d => new
        {
            d.Foo,
            Narrowed = d.Matches.Where(m => d.Foo.Stackability.Contains(m.FooId))
        })
        .SelectMany(d => d.Narrowed.Select(n => new { Foos = new List<Int32> { d.Foo.FooId, n.FooId}, BarSum = d.Foo.Bar + n.Bar}))
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.BarSum)
        .First();

    Console.WriteLine($"{{ {String.Join(", ", result.Foos.Select(f => $"Foo {f}"))} }} - Bar == {result.BarSum}");
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public int Bar { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains list of FooId
    /// </summary>
    public int[] Stackability { get; set; }
}
```

As it returns the following:

> { Foo 1, Foo 3 } - Bar == 11